# Rename directory with tar

Tags: tar

I have some directories, I want to pack into a tgz archive:

```
/home/stofl/myproject/migrations/
/home/stofl/myproject/source/
/path/to/my/migration/tool/source/
```

The archive should have the following structure:

```
migrations/
source/
my_migration_tool/
```

Do I have to copy the migration tool into `/home/stofl/myproject/` (or create a symlink) or is there another way?

**EDIT**

The archive could be compressed with `gzip` later. So maybe there is a way to append the directory to the `tar` archive with `--append`, but I didn't find a way to tell `tar` to use a different name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the archive should have relative paths (`migrations/` `source/` `my_migration_tool/`) there would have to be an archive made from `/home/stofl/myproject`.

As you mention you could append a directory to the tar archive (`tar` only permits appending for non-gzipped archives). But this would not rename the 3rd directory to my_migration_source:

```
cd /home/stofl/myproject
tar cvf myprojects.tar migrations source
/path/to/my/migration
# appends contents of tool to archive
tar -rv --file /home/stofl/myproject/myprojects.tar tool
```

The easiest option I think would be to use a symbolic link-:

```
cd /home/stofl/myprojec 
ln -s my_migration_tool /path/to/my/migration/tool/source/
# tar H option to follow symbolic links
tar cvfH myprojects.tar migrations source my_migration_tool
```

Comment: Yes thank you. I think I'll do that (but the option is `h`, not `H`, I think). I found an `--xfrom` parameter, but thats a bit too much for me now to find the right expression (if there is one).